# use fabric on localhost

Tags: python, fabric

I'd like to use `fabric` to do stuff on my local machine in lieu of shell scripts.

*For example*, I'd like to check if a directory exists, and if it doesn't create that directory.

I can run stuff locally using `local('ls')`, but I'd like to use the other functionality in `fabric` like `fabric.contrib.files.exists(path)`.

I've tried to `RTFM` but the lack of examples doesn't help.

**How can I run, for example,  `fabric.contrib.files.exists('/path/to/test')` on my localhost using fabric?**

---

Here's what works for `ls` using `local()`:

```
from fabric.api import local
def test():
    local('ls')
```

And here's a kind of janky solution that requires that I `ssh` onto my `localhost` to accomplish the task:

```
from fabric.api import env
from fabric.contrib import files
env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1']
def test():
    if files.exists('/Users/ryan'):
        print 'path exists!'
```

So I'd like the ease of `local()` with the functionality of everything else that comes with `fabric`.

Comment: Show us some example code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to `fabric` short of allowing loopback `ssh` connections you can't do much with their helper functions. `local()` (https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/1.11.1/fabric/operations.py#L1219) is just short for `subprocess`.. and a few more lines of code you will normally have to write, im not saying its useless, because i've used it in several occasions, but the `os` lib can do WAY more than that.

Theres an old expression, find the right tool for the job.

`exists()` (https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/1.11.1/fabric/contrib/files.py#L18) is running `tests -e <file path>` which will return a 0 is all is well or a 1 if it doesnt exist. -- can you already see this getting so ugly and out of hand that when you come back 3 months from now and look at this you'll be even more confused?!?!

if you really want to use `local()` do `local(test -e <file path>)` .. i still say just use `os`.

-- ps, don't use `local(ls)` -- like theres no need for that, `subprocess` is expensive, the `os` module is SO fast, and nice... `os.listdir('.')` why won't you just see the light?! :P

---

### Answer to old question question

Local? Use `os` as in `os.path.isfile(<file>)` or `os.path.isdir(<dir>)` there is no point for fabric to support it since the `os` lib is so well maintained.

Comment: I'd like to leverage all the benefits of `fabric` other than just checking if a path exists, which is why I'd like to solve the problem with `fabric`. The question is more of a demo example.

Comment: @RyanTuck your question was specific to checking if a directory existed; you cannot use fabric since fabric has no such function. Fabric is great for remote management, not really a tool to be used in your local box. At least not for this exact purpose.

Comment: good point - I've edited the title of the question to be more broad.

Comment: @RyanTuck the answer is still the same man, fabric was not created to manage your local machine through the use of -- pretty much anything inside `fabric.api` it was meant for your to connect to "remote" machine and run things there. I think i understand what youre trying to do, youre trying to setup your local machine and/or production machine and you dont want duplicate boiler code and are frustrated by it? yes? if so, all you need to do is open up ftp/ssh on your machine and tell fabric to connect to localhost -- youre done, you can use `fabric.files.exists()` now :D

Comment: @RyanTuck `ssh`ing into your own box is not wonky.

Comment: I guess you're right - I was under the impression that there would be a more elegant solution to the problem. and you're right about what i'm intending to do. I'll continue on with the `ssh` strategy and should be good to go - and i promise i'll look into the `os` module further ;) - thanks!